Calculating Saturation Magnetization from Atomic Moments
I'm attempting to calculate the saturation magnetization ($M_s$) of a material based on the value of atomic magnetic moments. For instance, iron's saturation magnetization is commonly reported as 2 T (Tesla) and also known to be $2.23 \mu_B$ per atom. However, when we try to convert by simply multiplying the value of $\mu_B$,
$$
1 \mu_{B} = 9.274 × 10^{-24} Am^2
$$
$$
M_s (Tesla) = \mu_B × (9.274 × 10^-24) =  2.07 × 10^{-23} T
$$
The obtained a value of approximately $2.07 × 10^{-23}$ T,  is $10^{23}$ times smaller than the repeated value. What am I missing here? How can we calculate the saturation magnetization in Tesla of a bulk material if we know the atomic moment in $\mu_B$.
